# C sum of digits raised to the power of their position

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a C program that calculates the sum of digits of a number raised to the power of their position.

Ex: 
User inputs `5672`,
Output should be `5^1 + 6^2 + 7^3 + 2^4`.
The first digit in the number `5` is raised to the power `1` because it's the first digit. It's the same logic in every case.

I have come up with the code to calculate the sum of digits of a number, however, I'm having trouble generating the code about how to raise these numbers to a certain power.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    long num, digit, sum = 0;
    int countDigits = 0;
    long temp = num;
    int i;

    printf("Enter the number \n");
    scanf("%ld", &num);
    temp = num;
    while (num > 0) {
        digit = num % 10;
        sum  = sum + digit;
        num /= 10;
    }
    printf("Given number = %ld\n", temp);
    printf("Sum of the digits %ld = %ld\n", temp, sum);

    while (temp > 0) {
      countDigits += 1;
      temp /= 10;
    }

    i = 0;
    sum = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        digit = num % 10;
        sum = sum + pow(digit, countDigits);
        countDigits -= 1;
        num /= 10;
    }

    printf("The final sum is %d\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: add a `position` variable before the loop, initialise it to 1, increment it at the end of the loop and change `sum  = sum + digit;` to `sum  += pow(digit,pos);`

Comment: [Do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821270/c-program-that-calculates-sum-of-digits-of-a-number-raised-to-the-power-of-their#comment72754348_42821270) or use a for loop, and there you will have the "*position*" `pos` variable `for (int pos = 1 ; num > 0 ; ++pos)`.

Comment: @George That's a great idea, but unfortunately the code above is getting at the digits from right to left, and she wants to read the digits from left to right.  It might be better all around to read in a string, and do it that way.  Step through the string until it's not a number, decoding actual digits from characters (char - '0').  Then your position logic would be cool... (but of course she'd have to take into account that pos would range from 1 to n, but when dereferencing the string to be sure to use "pos-1".

Comment: From a mathematical view, the digist start from the rightmost. And that position would be `0`, not `1`.

Comment: @BradBales ah crud, totally missed that; thanks for pointing it out. Looks like an answer corrected the oversight :-)

Comment: You are printing sum with %d which is not correct for long. Use %ld

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty simple, create an extra function where you send it the digit position + the digit it self, the function will return digit^i. Add that to the sum.

```
int countDigits = 0
int temp = num
while (temp > 0)
{
    countDigits += 1;
    temp /= 10;
}

i = 0;
sum = 0;
while (num > 0)
{
    digit = num % 10;
    sum  = sum + pow(digit, countDigits);
    countDigits -= 1;
    num /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the requirements are to read the digits from left to right.  The original code and this code does it from right to left...

Comment: @BradBales count number of digits, then start working on the number the same way and decrement the counter number of digits after calling pow function.

Comment: Thank you @TonyTannous appreciate it, however does this code work for the digits from left to right as in the example?

Comment: @KaraWetzelC yes it does.

Comment: Hey @TonyTannous so I updated the code according to your instructions and it still gives me the wrong answer. The updated code can be found in the latest edit to the question.

Comment: Can you edit so it gives out the right answer and help me figure out how you did?

Comment: @KaraWetzelC yes sure. One moment

Comment: @KaraWetzelC remove the first while loop... you have 3 while loops and you don't need the first.

Comment: @TonyTannous I did remove the while loop but the code still returns the wrong value...

Comment: What input did you try ?

Comment: Did you remove the forst while loop?

Comment: And use int for a while instead of long

Comment: Yeah I removed the first while loop. Okay hold on.

Comment: `double pow(double, double)` is subject to slightly non-whole valued  results, even whole-valued operands.  `pow(7,7)` may result in `823542.9999...` and then truncate to `823542` on `int` assignment.  Better to avoid `<math.h>` functions for an integer problem.

Comment: @Chux I used my own ipow function so I guess Op also has his own and is not using the one from math. A simple search in google with give him results for a self implemented pow.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reading the number in and then trying to sum up the powered digits, it's a little easier to do it all at once.

Here's a solution, that uses `ipow` -- raising `x` to the power `n` using exponentiation by squaring. You could equally well replace this with a loop that goes `n` times, since your `n` can't get very large.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long ipow(long x, int n) {
    long r = 1;
    while (n) {
        if (n % 2) r *= x;
        x *= x;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return r;
}

int main() {
    long sum = 0;

    printf("Enter the number \n");
    long n = 0;
    for (int pos = 1; ; pos++) {
        int c = getchar() - '0';
        if (c < 0 || c > 9) break;
        sum += ipow(c, pos);
        n = 10 * n + c;
    }
    printf("Number is: %ld\n", n);
    printf("Powered digit sum is: %ld\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: He's probably learning [Tag:C] just now and it would just confuse him at this stage. A recursion would be cool but I don't think he still knows it as well.

Comment: Suggest consistency `if (n % 2) ... n/=2;` or  `if (n & 1) ...   n >>= 1;`.  The first is more portable.